# Crashlytics fails to initialize plugin in Android Studio 1.0.2

Tags: android-studio, crashlytics

Getting the following error after adding CrashlyticsPlugin.jar to Android Studion 1.0.2... any suggestions?

I was only able to get studio to add the jar file... It would not accept if I re-zipped plugin folder to a zip file.

```html
Plugin 'com.crashlytics.tools.androidstudio' failed to initialize and will be disabled.  Please restart Android Studio.

java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of com/intellij/ide/plugins/cl/PluginClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of com/intellij/ide/plugins/cl/PluginClassLoader) for resolved class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:299)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.bootstrap.osgi.OsgiBootstrapper.<clinit>(OsgiBootstrapper.java:54)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.CrashlyticsPlugin.initComponent(CrashlyticsPlugin.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:548)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:225)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:199)
    at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.getComponentInstance(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:371)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:89)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:508)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:151)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:46)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Ensure that you are importing the ZIP and not the actual folder that is extracted.

Answer (score 7):

Select the zip file instead of jar.

Answer (score 6):

Downloading the plugin using Chrome instead of Safari seemed to fix the problem.. Safari was automatically unzipping the file.

Comment: to disable this in safari: preferences > general > uncheck "Open 'safe' files after downloading"